# set bundle to intent URL

Tags: android

please help me on my application. I want to use some URL use bundle and intent but I don't know how to do.
I have some setData to access some URL.
I use Fragment.java, Home.java for set data and Adapter.java.

this is my Fragment.java:

```
 list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new HomeAdapter(getActivity(),list) {
        @Override
        public void onProductSelected(Home model) {
            //on klik ke page NewsActivity
           // Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewsActivity.class);
           // startActivity(intent);

        }
    };

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleViewHome);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    setData();

    return view;
}
public void setData()
{
    list.clear();

    Home home = new Home();
    home.setJudul("Judul Berita");
    home.setDetail("detail berita");
    home.setURL("");
    home.setGambar("");
    list.add(home);
    home = new Home();
    home.setJudul("Judul Berita");
    home.setDetail("detail berita");
    home.setURL("");
    home.setGambar("");
    list.add(home);
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not clear enough and your code seems to be incomplete. Please edit your message to indicate what you want, what you've done and what is your problem

Comment: i need to input some source code to acces URL from my applicaton, and i don't know the source code